# Pytest import error despite using conftest in root directory?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have the following directory structure:

```
src 
    \conftest.py
    \dir_A
        \run_A.py
        \test_run_A.py
    \dir_B
        \run_B.py
```

where run_A.py has the following code:

```
from dir_B import run_B

...
```

When I run `pytest` from `src`, I get the error:

```
ImportError while importing test module '/home/user/src/dir_A/run_A.py'
...

ImportError: cannot import name 'run_B'
```

Is there a reason why this fails despite using conftest.py?

I'd like to add that running `python3 -m dir_A.test_run_A` from `src` works perfectly fine as a test.

Comment: What happens if you do `from dir_B.run_B import foo` where `foo` is a function in `run_B.py`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it says that run_B is not a package, strangely.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but what version of Python are you using?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Python 3.6

Comment: How are you running your tests? From the command line or from an IDE? What is PYTHONPATH?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm running from a command line, using simply `pytest`. python path is from using conda.

Comment: Does anything change when invoking pytest using `python -m pytest`?

Comment: Sounds like `dir_B` is found but differs from your expectations. What does `import dir_B`, then `print(dir_B)` output?

Comment: Cannot reproduce no matter how hard I tried, screenshot of demo https://i.imgur.com/j2L8Ten.png

Answer (score 0):

You'll find this link helpful: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/pythonpath.html

Essentially, when running these tests from the `src` directory, `pytest` will walk all the way down to `/home/user/src/dir_A/run_A.py`. Without any `__init__.py` files, it will then *refuse* to walk anywhere else, as it doesn't realize it is part of a larger package.